# Write back cache formula with write allocate policy

Tags: caching, x86, cpu, cpu-architecture

If we consider an **hierarchical single level write back cache** with **write allocate policy**, then the formula for average access time during **write operation** is given by :-

Twrite = (H)(Tc) + (1-H)(Tc + Tm + (x*Tm)).

Where,

H= hit ratio of cache.

Tc=access time of cache.

Tm= access time of memory.

x= fraction of cache blocks which are dirty.

The above formula is given in this site https://gateoverflow.in/14480/formula-write-back-write-through-access-time-parallel-serial?show=14502#a14502

However, I think that formula is not entirely correct. According to me, during a **write miss** in case of write allocate,we first find a block to replace in the cache and if its dirty, 
 we update the main memory. Now we bring the required cache block which contains the word into the cache and then **update the cache**. This is what I read in hamacher and patterson book.

So shouldn't the formula be

Twrite = (H)(Tc) + (1-H)(Tc + Tm + (x*Tm) + **Tc**). ?

Here I have added the **extra Tc** time at the end which is required to update the word in the cache once the block has been brought from main memory. 
First Tc is the time we add in case of miss because its **hierarchical** cache

Comment: If it's a single-level cache, in what sense is it hierarchical?

Comment: @PeterCordes Hierarchical in the sense, we access memory only after checking if it's in cache in a sequential manner. In case of simultaneous access, we can search both in cache and memory simultaneously (not in sequential manner from cache to mem). Did you check the link which I have posted ? Are the formulas correct?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.    "Hierarchical" in that sense is pretty much the standard design for CPU caches, for power and performance reasons.  Building a large cache that can start (and abandon) an operation every clock is hard, even if it doesn't have to be low latency.  It's more plausible with a multi-level cache, but still not something you see in any mainstream CPUs, AFAIK.  I think even building hardware to send the request off to the outer cache in parallel might slow down the fast path by a cycle.  And no, I don't have time right now to look at cache basics.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok. But can you just tell if my understanding about the mechanism and the formula is correct or not?  You can look at the link later.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check the write allocate policy again. There is a really good [paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/173682.165154) on Write miss polocies by Norman P. Jouppi.

As the name suggests, write allocate, allocates an entry in the cache in case of a write miss. If the line that is allocated for the write miss is dirty, we need to update the main memory with the contents of the dirty cache line. So the amount of time spent on updating the main memory for dirty cache lines would be

```
x * Tm
```

After you've updated the main memory with the contents of the dirty cacheline, you can use it to store the data for the write miss. Therefore we need to access the cache. So our new time would be

```
Tc + (x * Tm)
```

However we would only do this, when there is a cache miss. Therefore the whole thing needs to be multiplied by the miss rate.

```
(1-H)(Tc + (x * Tm))
```

Above formula covers the case when it is a miss. When it is a hit, we just need to access the cache. That would be Tc times the hit rate

```
Tc * H
```

Adding them all gives us the average access time:

```
(Tc * H) + (1-H)(Tc + (x * Tm))
```

Comment: So the reason you add Tc time in case of miss is because you update the word in cache after bringing the block from main memory to the cache right ? Did you check the link which I posted in the question?

Comment: I think you also need to add Tm in case of miss because that would be the time required to bring the block from main memory to the cache.

Comment: If you check the paper I've cited, you'll see there are options you do on a write miss. "fetch-on-write" or "no-fetch-on-write". If the former is used, you need to add Tm to the part of the formula that is multiplied by the miss rate. But if the latter is used, the formula given is correct.

Comment: You need to add Tc one more time right ? Because it's **hierarchical** access . Because we already spent Tc time first looking into the cache for a hit.

Comment: Good thinking, but usually when we say cache access time, it is usually meant the time to access the cache and get the data. So at the beginning, the time we spent looking for the line is not the cache access time, its a bit less than that.

Comment: Yes, it's bit less than that. That's the reason we multiply it with hit probability in case of cache hit. So shouldn't the miss case be (1-H)( Tc + x*Tm + Tm + Tc) for fetch on write ?

Comment: For fetch on write, formula is (1-H)( Tc + x*Tm + Tm). Tc is the time to access the cache and get the data. We spent a bit of time (say t1 time) to know its a miss. Then we fetch the data (Tm). Then we return data (say t2 time). So t1+t2 is the time to access the cache and return data which is Tc.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still not convinced with your formula . The Tc time you added in case of miss is the time required to update the word **after** bringing the required block from main memory to the cache right ? I think we should add (1-H)(Tc) again in case of hierarchical access. For simultaneous access you need not add (1-H)(Tc).